# Correct way to handle fatal error under Play framework

Tags: error-handling, playframework, playframework-2.4

If your Play app discovers it is unable to operate, for instance because of missing mandatory configuration items, what is the correct way of handling that?

Log an error and System.exit() ? Or is there a "nicer" way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a little research, it seems there [is a method](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/Play.scala) for closing down the actual play application but this does not shut down the app server (e.g. Netty) (at least in dev mode). Combining this with `System.exit()` appears to do a "safe" shutdown by first dealing with Play:

```
play.api.Play.stop
System.exit(-1)
```

But it will be interesting to test it in your specific circumstances.

[This discussion](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/1789) talks more about the meaning of shutting down safely and has an example of Play.stop being called.

BTW, Netty seems to have [a stop method](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.4/api/scala/index.html#play.core.server.NettyServer), which does a few other things besides the `Play.stop` call.

Caveat: have not used this in anger.